# MFC DateTimePicker crash app when open calendar widget

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, datetimepicker

I work on a C++/ MFC app on Visual Studio 2013, Win7 32bit. I have a Main application with a dialog where I put a DateTimePicker MFC object. For the initilization I used the `DDX_DateTimeCtrl` and a `m_odtFilterData` member variable.

```
void CClassDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_DateTimeCtrl(pDX, IDC_DATE, m_odtFilterData);
}

BOOL CClassDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    COleDateTime odtCurrDate = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
    m_odtFilterData.SetDate(odtCurrDate.GetYear(), 1, 1);

    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    //etc etc
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    return TRUE;
}
```

After I added a Date Time Change event

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CClassDlg, CDialog)
ON_NOTIFY(DTN_DATETIMECHANGE, IDC_DATE, &CClassDlg::OnDtnDatetimechange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

and

```
void CClassDlg::OnDtnDatetimechange(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMDATETIMECHANGE pDTChange = reinterpret_cast<LPNMDATETIMECHANGE>(pNMHDR);

    if(m_odtExampleODTVarThatIHave > m_odtFilterData)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

The **problem** is that when in the dialog I choose the date with the datetimepicker, sometimes, the app crash with this error:

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in AppName.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in AppName.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while AppName.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

The output only says:

```
HEAP[AppName.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 279850 modified at 279e1c after it was freed
```

And the breakpoint is stucked at mfc\appmodul.cpp:

```
extern "C" int WINAPI
_tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
#pragma warning(suppress: 4985)
{
    // call shared/exported WinMain
/*->*/return AfxWinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);
}
```

**It's very strange and happens only few click on the button of the datetimepicker that shows the months widget. If, instead of the widget, I use the Spin Control all works perfectly... Do you have any idea?**
[The button that open the month widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOjJF.png)

Another thing, if I remove the

```
if(m_odtExampleODTVarThatIHave > m_odtFilterData)
```

all works. It seems that for some reason, the *m_odtFilterData* variabile gets corrupted by month widget. I don't understand where is my error.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem that I see is that you forgot to call `CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);` in `CClassDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)` So it should look like:

```
void CClassDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_DateTimeCtrl(pDX, IDC_DATE, m_odtFilterData);
}
```

Please also check that Common Controls have been properly initialized in `OnInitInstance` of your `CWinApp`-derived class:

```
 INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex = { sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX), ICC_DATE_CLASSES | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES };

 // Init the common controls.
 InitCommonControlsEx ( &iccex );
```

Please also make sure you have proper manifest:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Please also check your `_WIN32_WINNT` definition.

Comment: And the second one - you need to call `CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();` from `OnInitDialog()` before accessing any child controls.

Comment: @Vlad: Totally agree. Good catch.

Comment: Nope, I only forgot the two instructions in the copy-paste of my code: I have pasted only the main part of the code, where I have the problem , because I have other things on dialog like an edit control, a ctrl list etc but all works perfectly before I use the datetimepicker... any other idea? I edited the question

Comment: Please move the `CDialog::OnInitDialog();` to the top of your `OnInitDialog()`

Comment: @user3378687: Do not ever change code when posting a question. Produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that, unabridged. If the code you post, and the question you ask do not match, it stops being useful, both to other users and yourself.

Comment: AndrewKomiagin I have tried but nothing changed 
@IInspectable Yes, you have reason but the code is too big to produce a MCVE in a fast way. In any case I will try to produce an example if is necessary

Comment: Did you initialize common controls in `OnInitInstance()` of your `CWinApp`? I've updated the answer to help you out.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin Common Controls and InitIstance() are ok infact all other parts of this app doesn't have problems. I have noticed that is something about focus. If instead of "//do stuff" in the code I show a small Modal custom dialog with a button (like a popup), when i close the dialog clicking on OK button I have that error...

Comment: Maybe your small modal dialog corrupts the memory? Post the code of this dialog. It could be a root cause of your problem.

Comment: Nope it's not the dialog because I use it as a simple popup in other softwares and in other parts of this software and all works fine. I'm working on this issue and now I saw that if I use the datetimechange event, when I choose the months with the arrows in the widget he detect that the date is changed although the widjet is open. So I have tried to use the CLOSEUP event instead of DATECHANGE and the problem disappear of the heap disappear. But now I can detect the change of the date only through the widget..I want that the user is able to write the date also with keyboard avoiding the error.

Comment: Your heap is somehow corrupted. I believe it is not related to CDateTimeCtrl. You'll have to analyze the entire app source code to find the problem. Have you tried running this app on another PC?

Comment: If is not related to the datetimepicker, why I have the error only in the "if" where I use the member variable of the date? I'm quite sure that all the other parts of app are fine. I discovered that if I use a timer to call the OnChangeDate and OnClose event, all works fine...I put the timer because I want to give the time to the user to modify the enitire date instead of a single number. I want to investigate more and create an empty solution with fews dialog and test it...

Comment: It is good idea to create an empty project with just one `CDialog`-based window to see if you still have this problem. Also I'd suggest testing it on another PC.